# The problem of changing the tippy text via jq

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tippyjs

Sorry to bother you. I use Tippy.js v6.3.7 and there was a problem
There is a "div" element with "data-tippy-content="Save"". By means of JQ, I change to the text "Delete", but when hovering, the hints are covered on top of each other. I need only a new "Delete" label to appear. Please help me to sort out the problem, all cookies

```
        $.each(array, function(index, val) {
            var element_ = '.js-btn[data-id="' + val +'"]';
            $(element_).removeAttr("data-tippy-content");
            tippy(element_, {
                content: 'Delete',
            });
        });
```

Abbreviated version - https://codepen.io/yotavet814/pen/JjawZGd

Instance.destroy() instance method doesn't work, but other instance methods do https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/methods/#destroy

Comment: _sitting and thinking for an hour_. Hmm. This is one of my favourite ways of debugging.

Comment: @CodeThing I tried using the instance.destroy() method, but it didn't seem to work, other instance methods work [link](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/methods/#destroy)

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: @CodeThing Here, take a look, please - [link](https://codepen.io/yotavet814/pen/JjawZGd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. You can get instance by appending ._tippy to the element. And then you can use any instance method like setContent etc

```
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
  
tippy('[data-tippy-content]', {
        duration: [95, 95],
        theme: 'user',
        allowHTML: true,
        animation: 'scale',
        dynamicTitle: true,
});

const instance= btn._tippy;

instance.setContent("Delete");
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/prashantsk/pen/abaPKqN)

Comment: Great solution, you helped me a lot! Everything seems to work, but the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_tippy')" occurs and the rest of the scripts stop working, but this piece works

Comment: Where you are seeing this error?

Comment: Not sure what your actual code is. But from the error it looks like you are using ._tippy on wrong element. It should be the same element on which tippy is initialised.

Comment: And instance is available only after its initialisation. You probably calling it before this, hence the error. Hope this helps.

Comment: I found a bug! It turns out that after initializing this class, it cannot be deleted via removeClass, apparently then tippy somehow accesses this class later..